# Using conditional icons in customizable Angular data table

Tags: javascript, angular

I'd like to use content projection to "project" custom icons in an Angular data table I've made. I've attempted to make these icons conditional based on the data in a certain column. I am able to insert an icon into each column and row, but I am unable to figure out how to make these conditional.

table.component.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols" 
            (click)="selectColHeader(col.prop); 
            col.enableSort && sort(col.prop)">
                {{col.header}}
                <input type="text"
                class="ds-c-field"
                [(ngModel)]=fields[col.prop] 
                (click)="selectColInput(col.prop, $event)"
                *ngIf=col.enableFilter/>
                <img 
                class="arrow"
                *ngIf="col.enableSort && col.prop === selectedColHeader"
                [src]="direction === 'asc' ? upArrowPath : downArrowPath"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let row of data">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                    <ng-container 
                    *ngTemplateOutlet="cellTemplate;
                     context: row[col.prop]">
                    </ng-container>
                {{row[col.prop]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.component.html

```
<app-data-table
[data]="data" 
[cols]="cols" 
[cellTemplate]="cellTemplate">
    <ng-template #cellTemplate let-value>
        <img class="rimg1" 
        [src]="com" 
        alt="Complete"
        *ngIf="value === 'Completed'/>
    </ng-template>
</app-data-table>
```

table.component.ts

```
export class tableComponent {

  @Input() cellTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **table.component.html**
try change rows `<ng-container ..... ></ng-container>` to:

```
<ng-container 
   *ngTemplateOutlet="cellTemplate;
      context: {prop1: row[col.prop] }"> // <-- changes here
</ng-container>
```

And in **app.component.html** change row
`<ng-template #cellTemplate let-value>`
to :
`<ng-template #cellTemplate let-value="prop1">`

After the changes, it should work.

Comment: The only solid answer I could find. Thank you!